# Skip lines until the next block in a text file if a condition is met in PYthon

Tags: python, text, io, text-files

I have a huge text file consisting of "blocks" like this:

```
block
object pen
fruit apple
people mike
block
electronic laptop
city dallas
fruit banana
object stapler
vehicle car
block
people george
fruit orange
vehicle truck
city austin
object hammer
```

In each block there is only one fruit at a random line. Each block has different number of lines. I want to iterate in this file, print everything including the fruit's name, and then skip until the next block. Once I find the fruit in one block, it is a waste of time to check if the next line is fruit or not. I just want to jump to the next block, but the problem is I don't know how many lines ahead the block is. So the output should look like:

```
block
object pen
the fruit is: apple
block
electronic laptop
city dallas
the fruit is: banana
block
people george
the fruit is: orange
```

I can produce this output in two ways, one:

```
flag = True
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.split()[0] == 'fruit':
            print "the fruit is: " + line.split()[1]
            flag = False
        if line.split()[0] == 'block':
            flag = True
        if flag:
            print line
```

And two:

```
flag = False
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.split()[0] == 'fruit':
            print "the fruit is: " + line.split()[1]
            flag = True
        if line.split()[0] == 'block':
            flag = False
        if flag:
            continue
        print line
```

But this is not what I want. My code still checks each line whether it is fruit. I want to skip the lines after fruit until block, and continue from there. How can I do that jump?

Comment: `if flag and line.split()[0] == 'fruit':` just test for the flag to avoid comparison

Comment: Your second piece of code is already what you're asking...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def not_block(line): return line != 'block\n'
def not_fruit(line): return not line.startswith('fruit ')

with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
    while True:
        for line in takewhile(not_fruit, dropwhile(not_block(f)):
            print line.rstrip()
        fruitline = next(f, None)
        if fruitline:
            print "the fruit is: " + fruitline.split()[1]
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an inner loop that you trigger after you find a `block` line. Note that this assumes your data is well-formed (i.e., every block has a fruit).

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == 'block':
            print(line)
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                if line.startswith('fruit '):
                    print('the fruit is:', line.split(None, 1)[1])
                    break
                else:
                    print(line)
```

Another thing you can do that's a bit more involved but could be a lot faster if the data file is truly huge is use [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html) with [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap.find).

Answer (score 0):

Call me crazy but I want to take a different dig at this with `list comprehension` and `zip()`:

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in file.readlines()]

blocks = [i for i, j in enumerate(lines) if j == 'block']
fruits = [i for i, j in enumerate(lines) if 'fruit' in j]

for i, j in zip(blocks, fruits):
    print('\n'.join(lines[i:j+1]))
```

**Output:**

```
block
object pen
fruit apple
block
electronic laptop
city dallas
fruit banana
block
people george
fruit orange
```

But that'll *only work* if each `block` is always followed by a `fruit` before the next `block`.

It looks pretty, okay.  Don't question my weapon of choice...

Comment: This reads all the lines into memory up front, which for a large file might be too slow or use too much memory. It also iterates over the lines twice. It is pretty clever, though.

Comment: Ah shoot forgot the big list part of the requirements.  Ah well, all in good fun.